# Компонент не работает app первый?

Tags: vue.js

Не работает компонент app

```js
Vue.component('app', {
  props: {
    max: Number,
    val: Number
  },
  computed: {
    width() {
      let w = this.val / this.max * 100;
      return {
        width: w + '1%'
      }
    }
  },
  template: ` 
    <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar" v-bind:style="width"></div>
 </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers: [],
    maxNumbers: 3
  },
  methods: {
    AddNumber() {
      this.numbers.push(Math.random());
    },
    sum() {
      let sum = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numbers.length; i++) {
        sum += this.numbers[i];

      }
      return sum;
    },
    done() {
      return this.numbers.length >= this.maxNumbers;
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>Sum: {{sum()}}</div>
  <app v-bind:val="sum" v-bind:max="maxNumbers*5"></app>
  <hr>
  <app v-bind:val="numbers.length" v-bind:max="maxNumbers"></app>
  <button @click="AddNumber()">Add number</button>
  <li v-for="number in numbers">
    {{ number }}
  </li>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: первый компонент не работает. Он считает сумму чисел

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Метод `sum` сделал вычисляемым свойством - и все заработало

```js
    Vue.component('app', {
       props: {
        max: Number,
        val: Number
       },
       computed: {
        width() {
         let w=this.val/this.max*100;
         return {
          width: w+'1%'
         }
        }
       },
       template: ` 
        <div class="progress">
           <div class="progress-bar" v-bind:style="width"></div>
        </div>
       `
      })
     new Vue ({
      el: "#app",
      data: {
       numbers:[],
       maxNumbers: 3
      },
               computed:{
                  sum() {
          let sum=0;
       for (let i=0; i<this.numbers.length; i++) {
        sum+=this.numbers[i];
          }
        return sum;
       },
            },
      methods: {
       AddNumber() {
        this.numbers.push(Math.random());
       },
       
       done() {
        return this.numbers.length >= this.maxNumbers;
       }
      }
     })
```

```css
.progress-bar{
background: red;
height:1px;
}
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>Sum: {{sum}}</div>
  <app v-bind:val="sum" v-bind:max="maxNumbers*5"></app>
  <hr>
  <app v-bind:val="numbers.length" v-bind:max="maxNumbers"></app>
  <button @click="AddNumber()" >Add number</button>
  <li v-for="number in numbers">
   {{ number }}
  </li>
 </div>

 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
```

Comment: где была ошибка???

Comment: `sum` вычислялся только 1 раз, при создании. Нужно было реализовать его постоянное обновление

Comment: Хорошо, а где изменения в коде ?

Comment: я же написал: `Метод sum сделал вычисляемым свойством - и все заработало`

Comment: он же и так был в computed...

Comment: нет, он был в `methods`

Comment: верно, логично теперь все. хорошых празников

Answer (score 1):

```js
Vue.component('app', {
  props: {
    max: Number,
    val: Number
  },
  computed: {
    width() {
      return (this.val / this.max * 100) + '%'; 
    }
  },
  template: ` 
    <div class="progress">
     <div class="progress-bar" :style="{ width }"></div>
 </div>
  `
})
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    numbers: [],
    maxNumbers: 3
  },
  computed: {
    sum() {
      let result = 0;
      for (let i = 0; i < this.numbers.length; i++) {
        result += this.numbers[i];
      }
      return result;
    },
  }, 
  methods: {
    addNumber() {
      this.numbers.push(Math.random());
    },
    done() {
      return this.numbers.length >= this.maxNumbers;
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.progress-bar { height: 1rem; background: #44d; }
```

```html
<div id="app">
  <div>Sum: {{ sum }}</div>
  <app :val="sum" :max="maxNumbers * 5"></app>
  <hr>
  <app :val="numbers.length" :max="maxNumbers"></app>
  <button @click="addNumber">Add number</button>
  <li v-for="number in numbers">
    {{ number }}
  </li>
</div>

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.min.js"></script>
```

Логику прогрессбара я не понял - добавив стили для отображения и починив бинд, оставил ее как есть.